# Given a set of 64 integers, I must find all 8-integer subsets whose sum <= k

Tags: algorithm, set, combinations

With very rudimentary dynamic programming experience, I only have the web to turn to when it comes to this problem. Doing my research, it seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648661/given-a-set-s-find-all-the-maximal-subsets-whose-sum-k) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085680/given-a-set-of-n-integers-list-all-possible-subsets-with-sum-k) seem to be in the ball park of what I'm looking for, however, I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around what the code would look like given the requirement that all subsets have eight integers.

For example:

```
2678
2258
2146
2067
2026
1986
1967
1928
1844
1809
987
981
928
790
752
739
470
400
393
```

given this set, I must find every combination of eight integers that will sum to less than 10000.

I'm pretty new to posting on these forums, so if I overstepped some bounds please let me know. Any information would be helpful!
Thanks a ton, really appreciate it.

Comment: What you tried so far Chevy?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, SO is not a forum. It is a Q&A site about specific programming problems. Read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [Off-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: One possibility would be to follow the code / approach in the second linked answer. Only stop looking (for continuations of the set) when already having 8 values in the set. After all these sets of 1..8 numbers have been found throw out all sets without 8 elements. In any case, SO usually works 'better' when bringing in some code or a detailed outline.

Comment: Do you know how to generate all subsets of size 8? There are about 4 billion of those, so you can just calculate them all. Then add some pruning to speed it up (if the sum of, say, 4 elements already exceeds 10000, it is no use to add more numbers).

Answer (score 0):

If you use c# you have LINQ as a quite powerful tool at your disposal. Using LINQ you can actually achieve what you are looking for in an one-line query. With the integers from your example there are 14441 different combinations of 8 integers of which the sum is lesser than 10.000:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        //Set your input parameters.

            int[] input = { 2678, 2258, 2146, 2067, 2026, 1986, 1967, 1928, 1844, 1809, 987, 981, 928, 790, 752, 739, 470, 400, 393 };
            int SubsetCount = 8;
            int MaxSum = 10000;

        //Determine all subsets that are meeting your restrictions.
            var subsets = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << input.Length).Select(a => Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length).Where(i => Program.NumberOfSetBits(a) == SubsetCount && (a & (1 << i)) != 0).Select(i2 => input[i2])).Where(sub => sub.Sum() < MaxSum && sub.Sum() >= 1);

        //Print the result to the Console.
            foreach (IEnumerable<int> sub in subsets)
            {
                foreach (int s in sub)
                {
                    Console.Write(s.ToString() + "; ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static int NumberOfSetBits(int i)
        {
            i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
            i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
            return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
        }
    }
}
```

The solution with LINQ was not as trivial as i thought though and is admittedly not very easy to read. As a beginner to programming, i would suggest to start with a more procedual approach to you like suggested in the comments:

- determine all subsets of your input
- reduce that list to all subsets of size 8
- search the remainder for subsets with sum lesser than 10.000

Also I didn't test the code above with a full set of 64 integers. If runtime is an issue for you, there are some very reasonable optimizations that you can do if you implement the queries yourself rather than using LINQ.
(sorting the integers by size - and taking the difference to the next highest number into account - will allow you to build an algorithm that generates EXACTLY the desired resultset and stops as soon as you hit a combination that exeeds your limit of 10.000)

**Edit:**

Since i failed in formatting the LINQ query properly for better readability, i felt obligated to give some pointers on what it is doing:

`Enumerable.Range(0, 1<< input.Length)` is a list of integers from `0` to `2^input.length` and thus contains one integer for each element in the power set of `input`. I use this as basis for the query so that we do not have to generate the power set itself (notice that you can map the binary representation of these integers one-to-one to the power set: input[i] is included in a subset if and only if the bit at position i in the according integer is set).

Thus we can find all subsets containing of 8 integers by finding all integers in our Range with exactly 8 bits set (i found the included method `NumberOfSetBits` used for this somewhere here on SO).

Furthermore the statement `a & (1 << i)` returns `1` when the bit at position `i` is set in the integer `a` (checked by shifting 1 i steps to the left and use a logical AND operation). Using this we obtain several list of exactly `8` indices which fit to some numbers in our input-array.

We then can go on and check each of these sets for their sum and compare it to our boundary (and also check for the sum to be `>0` to exclude empty sets from our query result).

Answer (score 0):

You said doing some research. As the solution is quite simple, I'll give the *approach* though this seems homework. **The code (intentionally) misses short-cutting trying all numbers.**

The number of candidate solutions being `64! / (64 - 8)! / 8!` is a bit large. So a reduction is due. As you need all solutions, order the 64 integers increasing. Then start solving with & without a candidate taken from the next position.

```
int[] numbers = ... 64 numbers
Arrays.sort(numbers);

int[] result = new int[8];
solve(result, 0, 0, 0);

void solve(int[] result, int resultIndex, int total, int numberIndex) {
    if (resultIndex >= 8) {
        if (total <= sum) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        }
        return;
    }
    if (numberIndex >= 64) {
        return;
    }

    // Solve without current number
    solve(result, resultIndex, total, numberIndex + 1);

    // Solve with current number
    int currentNumber = numbers[numberIndex];
    result[resultIndex] = currentNumber ;
    solve(result, resultIndex + 1, total + currentNumber, numberIndex + 1);
}
```

The approach taken consists of trying a new candidate - or not -, and continue with the rest.

Comment: The number of combinations is `64! / (64-8)! / 8!`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much. This is actually for a personal project of mine involving fantasy team sports. You must choose 8 players, and each player has a given salary depending on their talent - with a max salary of k, so this is very helpful! I'll look into short-cutting the numbers myself :).

Comment: To compare your heuristics (=extra optimization code): at solve-with-current-number you can check `if (total + (8 - resultIndex) * currentNumber > sum) return;`